# Oracle SQL using correctly sum over partition

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to get some information from an already built table:

```
PIN     BS      DES     SPEND
12300   CRRT    001     $15 
12300   CN      001     $20 
12300   CRRT    002     $10 
12300   TRN     001     $5 
12300   PWR     001     $30 
12300   TRN     002     $5 
145000  PWR     001     $30 
145000  SOL     001     $1 
145000  CN      001     $20 
145000  SOL     002     $2 
145000  PWR     002     $40
```

I need the same PIN for each case that BS repeats and the SPEND value sum.

```
PIN     BS      SPEND
12300   CN      $20 
12300   CRRT    $25 
12300   PWR     $30 
12300   TRN     $10 
145000  CN      $20 
145000  PWR     $70 
145000  SOL     $3
```

But still trying to figure out how to order my query.

```
SELECT PIN, BS, 
SUM(SPEND) OVER (PARTITION BY BS ORDER BY DES) AS SUMSPEND, 
FROM DATA_TABLE ORDER BY PIN ASC
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

to get the output posted, you don't need the analytic version of the sum, just do

```
SELECT PIN, BS, SUM(SPEND) AS SUMSPEND
FROM DATA_TABLE 
group by pin, bs
ORDER BY PIN ASC;
```

Comment: Didn't work, I tried changing the order on the sum analytic.